# popover hover not triggering on dynamic images

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a div with multiple images with each image having a popover with content attached to it and it works fine. The problem I'm having is I wanted to trigger the image popover by hover and the method I'm using right now works fine for static images but When I dynamically add images to the main div and hover on that image a popover won't trigger. How can I adjust my code so that it also supports any dynamically added elements? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

To replicate click on the append button and scroll to the far right and hover on the newly added image, that image won't trigger a popover on hover but the other static ones do.

```js
function appendImg() {
  $('.infoBar').append('<div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"></div>')
}

var popOverSettings2 = {
  selector: '.infoBar .imgWrap',
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  trigger: "manual",
  placement: 'top',
  sanitize: false,
  animation: false,
  content: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.popover').css({
        'width': '20%',
        'height': '20%',
        'overflow': 'auto'
      })
    })
    $('.infoBarPopoverContent').append('<p>Popover stuff...</p>')
    return $('.infoBarPopoverContent').html();
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('.infoBar .imgWrap').popover(popOverSettings2)
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
      var _this = this;
      $(this).popover("show");
      $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
      });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
      var _this = this;
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $('.popover').popover('hide');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}

.infoBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  max-width: 95%;
  height: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  column-gap: 25px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.infoBar .imgWrap {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infoBar .imgWrap img {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infoBarPopoverContent {
  display: none;
}

.popover .popover-body {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onclick='appendImg()'>Click to append img</button>

<div class="infoBar" id="infoBar">
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
</div>

<div class="infoBarPopoverContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood from your code is that you have to attach the event listener after the dynamic append like this

First wrap up the event listener inside the function, then call the function after the append

```
function appendImg() {
  $('.infoBar').append('<div class="imgWrap"><img 
    src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100"></div>')
      addEvent();
 }

var popOverSettings2 = {
  selector: '.infoBar .imgWrap',
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  trigger: "manual",
  placement: 'top',
  sanitize: false,
  animation: false,
   content: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
  $('.popover').css({
    'width': '20%',
    'height': '20%',
    'overflow': 'auto'
  })
})
$('.infoBarPopoverContent').append('<p>Popover stuff...</p>')
return $('.infoBarPopoverContent').html();
   }
}
function addEvent(){
$(function() {
  $('.infoBar .imgWrap').popover(popOverSettings2)
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
      var _this = this;
      $(this).popover("show");
      $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
      });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
      var _this = this;
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $('.popover').popover('hide');
      }
    });
});
}
addEvent()
```

https://jsbin.com/rumabifiqo/edit?output